# HTML Events Not Working

Tags: html, events, vbscript

I know that this isn't rocket science but I just can't get a VBScript subroutine to run for the "OnClick" event.  I've mad the code as simplistic as possible as follows.

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Untitled 1</title>

<script type="text/vbscript" language="vbscript">

Sub btn1_OnClick
    MsgBox("This is a test.")
End Sub

</script>

</head>

<body>

<form id="myForm">

<input name="btn1" type="button" value="Click Me">

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

When I click on the button, the message box does not appear.  I'm sure it's something very basic that I'm overlooking but at this point, I'm at a loss.

Comment: What browser (and version) are you testing in?

Comment: Why are you using client side VBScript in HTML anyway? It's only supported by legacy versions of Internet Explorer. Microsoft have been killing it off for years.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that IE has depreciated VBScript in IE11.  However, if the following tag is added, it will work.

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">
```